# preventdefault inside if causing form to not submit when if is false

Tags: jquery

Using this code to pickup forms with a specific class and process certain actions:

```
$('.stripe_payment').submit(function(e) {
    var frm = $(this);
    var token_input = $('#' + frm.attr('token_input'));

    console.log("submit");

    console.log( $(token_input).val() );

    if($(token_input).val() == "") {
        console.log("empty tk");

        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: 'pk_test_kOFWqH1EnP8UcrS3AqCYd4mQ',
            image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
            locale: 'auto',
            token: function(token) {
                if(token.id) {
                    $(token_input).val(token.id);
                    $(frm).submit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        handler.open({
            name: 'Integra Telecommunications Ltd',
            description: '2 widgets',
            zipCode: true,
            currency: 'gbp',
            amount: 2000
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });
});
```

and my HTML form:

```
<form id="topup_form" class="stripe_payment" token_input="stripe_token" method="post" action="/telecoms/sms/balance?ac=<?php echo $account["sequence"]; ?>">
<input type="text" id="stripe_token" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="topup_submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Order Credits" />
</form>
```

When submitting the form, the handler opens fine and i enter the details.

`token.id` is then returned and populated in the input field within the form but the `$(frm).submit();` is not then submitting the form normally.

I've tried changing `$(frm).submit();` to `$(this).submit();` and also changing `return true;` to `return false;` but still the same

Comment: if the `if` is false, then i dont want to preventdefault. i only want to use the preventdefault if the `token_input` value is blank

Comment: hmm, I mean I want preventDefault if the `token_input` is blank and if its not blank then to submit the HTML form

Comment: thats correct, preventDefault should happen when the if is true (`if($(token_input).val() == "") {`)

Comment: verify that `if($(token_input).val() == "") {` is true ?

Comment: it is true when the form is first submitted, `console.log("empty tk");` is displaying in the console which is inside the `if`. then when `$(frm).submit();` is supposed to be called it does not show in the console

Comment: so i know that the `if` statement is working. its just the `$(frm).submit();` that is not working

Comment: Ok, so the first time it goes into the if, does the `handler`, but then the submit in the token method is not working, correct?

Comment: `$(token_input).val(token.id);` works and it populates the input but the `$(frm).submit();` does nothing

Comment: Do you see the `console.log("submit");` output a second time once it get the token back?

Comment: yes, that appears again the second time as does the value of `token_input` and the `console.log("empty tk");` does not display

Comment: That would suggest the submit is working.  Not seeing the empty tk shows that the if is false.  So if the form is not being submitted, then that would suggest there is something else script wise that is preventing the form from submitting, not this block of code you have.

Comment: Try doing `frm.get(0).submit()`.  This should execute the submit on the underlying form, not a jQuery object with the form, which should result in any submit handlers for the form that jQuery has being bypassed.

Comment: just got this back: `Uncaught TypeError: frm.get(...).submit is not a function`

Comment: Well that's odd.  What do you see in the console if you do `console.log(frm.get(0))` ?

Comment: i'll check - `$('#topup_submit').click();` seems to work which is the button but thats not an option because the button ID won't always be the same

Comment: `console.log(frm.get(0))` returns the form HTML

Comment: Yeah, I expected that, so I don't understand why it would think the submit method is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180019/discussion-between-charlie-and-taplar).